# Is my understanding of Media Types correct?

Tags: rest, media, hateoas

**1)** Assume that when *media type name* is set to "`X/xml`", the software agent **SA** is capable of identifying *Hypermedia controls* contained in *representation format* **RF**

**a)** If **SA** receives the following HTTP reply ( which contains **RF** ), then "`text`" part of the *media type name* `text/xml` informs **SA** that it should process **RF** as *plain XML* ( thus it shouldn't try to identify *Hypermedia controls* )?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
       ...
Content-Type: text/xml
       ...
<order xmlns=″...″>
       ...
  <link rel=...″
        href=...″/>
</order>
```

**b)** But if instead **SA** receives the following HTTP reply, then "`X`" part in *media type name* `X/xml` which informs **SA** that while processing **RF** it should also identify *Hypermedia controls*?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
       ...
Content-Type: X/xml
       ...
<order xmlns=″...″>
       ...
  <link rel=...″
        href=...″/>
</order>
```

**2)** If my understanding in **1)** is correct, then I assume all values preceding "`xml`" ( say "`X/vnd.Y`" in media type name `X/vnd.Y+xml` ) are used to inform *software agent* which **processing model** it should use with *xml document*?

**EDIT:**

I apologize in advance for being so verbose

**1)**

> To clarify, XML has no hypermedia controls. I assume you meant a
>   hypermedia-capable XML format such as Atom (application/atom+xml).

I know XML is just a markup language and thus has no *Hypermedia controls*. But my understanding is that if my *custom media type* `MyMedia/xml` identifies `BeMyLink` element ( defined within XML Schema namespace `MySchemaNamespace` ) as *Hypermedia control*, then when processing the following XML document in accordance with `MyMedia/xml` ( thus when `Content-Type` header is set to `MyMedia/xml` ), the `BeMyLink` element is considered a *Hypermedia control*:

```
<MyCreation xmlns="MySchemaNamespace">
      <BeMyLink rel="..."
                href="..."/>
</MyCreation >
```

?

**2)**

> Assuming "X" is "application ..."

Could you clarify what you've meant to say here? Perhaps that *media type name* is `application/xml`?

**3)**

> If "X" is not "application" but some other type, it may not be safe
>   for your agent to parse the document as such.

Doesn't X just describe ( in terms of *processing model* ) how *resource representation* should be interpreted/parsed? As such, couldn't I name `X` part of *media type name* `X/xml` anything I want ( say `blahblah/xml` ), as long as agents trying to process this *representation* ( received via HTTP response with `Content-Type header` set to `blahblah/xml` ) are aware ( ie know how to process this *representation* according to instructions given by `blahblah/xml` ) of media type `blahblah/xml`?

**2. EDIT**

**1)**

> This is why you should be using standard media types, rather than
>   custom media types -- because in the end, the media type itself is not
>   a driver of application behavior

Isn't a downside to using **standard media types** in that when *agent* receives a *resource representation*, it won't know just by checking *media type value* whether it semantically understands the *representation*, while with **custom media types**, *agent* can figure just by looking at *media type value* whether it knows the semantic meaning of a *resource representation*?

**2)**

> This is why you should be using standard media types ...

Then I also assume we should only be using standard ( ie those registered with IANA ) *rel values*?

**3)**

> Higher level application semantics are communicated through external
>   documentation, not the media type. Through the documentation of rels
>   and links and what the named values within the representation mean.

Perhaps I'm nitpicking, but ... you say *higher level semantics* should be communicated through external documentation and not *media type*, but then you note that documentation of *rel values* should convey *higher level semantics*. But aren't *rel values* in lots of cases ( not always, as *rel values* can also be independently defined, such as those registered with IANA ) considered as being part of a *media type*?

Thank you

Comment: seems pretty academic of a question. i would guess that most browsers simply compare full "content-type" values to a few hard-coded formats they know how to render.

Comment: @dandavis: My question is oriented more towards non-browser consumers, thus consumers participating in a machine-to-machine interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, XML has no hypermedia controls. I assume you meant a hypermedia-capable XML format such as Atom (`application/atom+xml`).

1a) From [RFC 2046 section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-3):

> Plain text is intended to be displayed "as-is". ... Other subtypes are to be used for enriched text in forms where application software may enhance the appearance of the text, but such software must not be required in order to get the general idea of the content.

In your example, your software agent receiving a response of `text/xml` may choose to enhance the display of the document (clickable links, syntax highlighting, etc). See note 1.

1b) Assuming "X" is "application" then yes, your agent may freely parse the document for hypermedia controls and use them for deciding future operation. If "X" is not "application" but some other type, it may not be safe for your agent to parse the document as such.

2. You're basically right. For more information, check out [RFC 6839 section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6839#section-4.1) and [RFC 3023](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023).

**Response to edits:**

A media type takes the form `type/[vnd.]subtype[+suffix]`. Since "type" is a little ambiguous in this context, we usually call it the "top-level media type." There's only a small handful of reasons to ever declare a new top-level media type, so unless you're *absolutely* sure you need it, stick with the standards: text, image, audio, video, and application. The `[vnd.]` is the optional vendor prefix which is used to denote non-standard subtypes. The `[+suffix]` is used to denote when your custom subtype is a specialization of an existing standard subtype.

If you want to define a custom XML format, use `application/vnd.mymedia+xml`. Using `application` indicates that the document is intended to be used in conjunction with programs as opposed to human display. Using `vnd.` indicates that it's non-standard. Using `+xml` means, well, that it's an XML document. And `mymedia` is the name of your subtype.

It's the subtype, not the top-level media type, that indicates what you refer to as the processing model. If an agent knew how to parse `vnd.mymedia+xml` it wouldn't (theoretically) matter if it was `application/vnd.mymedia+xml` or `audio/vnd.mymedia+xml` as both types refer to the same document format. Whether `audio/vnd.mymedia+xml` makes any sense or not is a separate issue.

Note 1: In practice, you can probably treat `text/xml` as `application/xml` without issue. However, you can't treat `application/xml` as `text/xml` due to the possibility of non-printable data.

Comment: If you have time, could you see the edit I made? And thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2):

You're basically on track. The media type represents the processing model for the representation. The processing model is what "knows" about hypermedia elements.

So, as mentioned, `text/xml` is not a hypermedia media type because raw XML has no concept of hypermedia controls. Whereas, XHTML is clearly a hypermedia media type.

The processing model based on the media type effectively represents the syntax of the representation, as well as some level of processing semantics at the MEDIA TYPE level.

What they do not do, is represent semantics at an APPLICATION level.

This is why you should be using standard media types, rather than custom media types -- because in the end, the media type itself is not a driver of application behavior.

Consider `application/vnd.invoice+xml`. This implies (based on the name) that this media represents some kind of type resource, such as an invoice. in contrast to simply `application/xhtml+xml`. The html format clearly has no "invoice" semantics, its not even implied.

By using generic media types, the clients and applications can layer their own semantics upon the representation as the application requires. Higher level application semantics are communicated through external documentation, not the media type. Through the documentation of rels and links and what the named values within the representation mean.

Addenda:

The media type is syntax, not semantics. When you get an HTML form from a request, for example, is the form for submitting address information? airport reservations? tax information? The HTML media type can represent all of these, but none of these are related to the HTML media type at all.

If you followed the "registerCar" rel, the odds are pretty high that the form you got back have something to do with registering a car, HTML has no say in it. But the details surrounding the "registerCar" rel are documented externally. There may well be markers in the representation, such as `<title>Car Registration Form</title>`, but, too is something delegated to the documentation. But there's no criteria that suggest that semantics of a resource representation is necessarily able to convey the semantics under which it is used.

If you got a form back with a name and address, who's name is it? Which address? If you do "GET /person/1/homeaddress", then it's fair to say that you got their home address. But introspection of the payload doesn't necessarily tell you that. It's all a matter of context.

As for media types that document rels, some do, some don't. Atom has some, HTML doesn't. HAL doesn't. IANA has a list of generic standardized rels, but those are independent of media type. They would be applicable in either HTML or HAL. They're orthogonal.

If you're going to use standardized rels, then you should stick close to the semantics as standardized, thus leveraging the standard and the wide knowledge that they bring. But in the end how your application processes different rels is up to your application.

Comment: If you can, please see the second edit I made. And thank